# UIButton not refresh when updating

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, refresh, ios12

I have a big problem, I create an serial UIbutton when I click manually on a button, I change the background color and fill color, and unclick color change for normal state.

but when my program select a random button, sequence is good, but the button not change on real time and don't see what is button is selected (no background color, not fill color) I don't understand why , I see on other question a possibility with setNeedsDisplay, setEnable, .... but don't work for my ...

have you resolve this refresh problem ? how I refresh my button (button.setNeedsDisplay() not work)

see my program for see, I use soundEnd boolean value when my mp3 ending play and nextSound boolean value when my button is on normal state. Sleep is use for slow loop and wait mp3 play ending , if not multiple choice not work ... I found this solution but not for background and fill color

Thanks !

```html
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by Thierry on 03/06/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Thierry  All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
let squareSize  = 100
let borderSpace = 20

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let zone3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: view.frame.width-20, height: view.frame.height-20))
        zone3.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(squareDraw(contentView: zone3))
        
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        for randomInt in 1..<13 {
        print(randomInt)
        let subview = self.view.viewWithTag(randomInt)
        let button = subview as! UIButton
        
            button.sendActions(for: .touchDown)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
            }
            
            sleep(3)
        
        }
        }
    }
        
        func squareDraw(contentView : UIView) ->UIView {
                
                    let widthScreen: Int = Int(contentView.bounds.width)
                    let heightScreen: Int  = Int(contentView.bounds.height)
                
                    let scaleFactorX = (widthScreen*100/((3 * squareSize) + (4 * borderSpace)))
                    let scaleFactorY = (heightScreen*100/((4 * squareSize) + (5 * borderSpace)))
                
                    let squareSizeScaleX = (squareSize * scaleFactorX)/100
                    let squareSizeScaleY = (squareSize * scaleFactorY)/100
                    
                    let borderSpaceScaleX = (borderSpace * scaleFactorX)/100
                    let borderSpaceScaleY = (borderSpace * scaleFactorY)/100
                
                
                let originY = 0
                var Tag = 0
                for yCoord in 1...4 {
                    for xCoord in 1...3 {
                        Tag = Tag + 1
                        let k = button(CGRect(x: xCoord * (squareSizeScaleX + borderSpaceScaleX) - squareSizeScaleX, y: originY + (yCoord * (squareSizeScaleY + borderSpaceScaleY) - squareSizeScaleY), width: squareSizeScaleX, height: squareSizeScaleY), tag: Tag)
                        contentView.addSubview(k)

                    }
                }
                return contentView

            }
            
        func button(_ rect: CGRect, tag: Int) ->UIView {

                let myButton = UIButton(type: .system)
                myButton.frame = CGRect(x:CGFloat(rect.minX), y:CGFloat(rect.minY), width:CGFloat(rect.width), height:CGFloat(rect.height))
                myButton.tag = tag
                myButton.backgroundColor = .white
                myButton.layer.borderWidth = 5
                myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonSelected), for: .touchUpInside)
                myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonReleased), for: .touchDown )
                return myButton
                
        }
        
      
    @objc func buttonSelected(sender: UIButton) {
                let button = sender
                
                if button.isSelected == true {
                   
                } else {
             
                      button.layer.borderWidth = 5
                      button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
                               
                }
            
            }
        
    @objc func buttonReleased(sender: UIButton) {
              
                let button = sender
             
                if button.isEnabled == true {

                    button.layer.borderWidth = 5
                    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
          
                } else {
                    
                }
            }

 
        
  


}
```

Comment: If you're running this on the main thread, you're probably going to have a lot of problems. If this is running on a background thread, you need to perform any UI updates on the main thread.

Comment: @DonMag thanks for response ! 
I don't other problems only color not change in real time on UIButton, all change is visible in end of loop, I not found how refresh my view after every change

result is the same with a loop 

'        for randomInt in 11..<23 {
          let subview = self.view.viewWithTag(randomInt)
          let button = subview as! UIButton
            
          button.layer.borderWidth = 5
          button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
          sleep(1)
            
        }'

Comment: Difficult to know exactly what your code is doing or what is affecting it. Can you put together a [mre]?

Comment: @DonMag I update in my first question code for example, without addTarget in button, it run automatically in xcode new project, if you have a soluce on this problem ? Thanks !

Comment: OK - your use of `sleep(2)` is a big problem. That "freezes" execution of your code for 2 seconds. If you remove that line, 3 seconds after your view loads all white squares will get black borders. Are you trying to change **one** border every 3 seconds?

Comment: @DonMag yes I trying to change one border every 1-3 seconds for create a sequence button 1 is color black , button 1 is white, button 2 is black, button 2 is white ....  , sleep 1 second is use for wait in my loop because I have sound for every button, I don't found how replace sleep function but pause necessary

Comment: A little confusing... do you want to: tap a button, change its background color, play a sound, when the sound ends change the background back? Or, do you have some number of sound clips, you want to change a rectangle color, play the sound, change the color back, change the next rectangle color, play the next sound, change the color back, etc?

Comment: @DonMag of course sorry for the confusion in my example, I update my code with button action, I want use button manually and I have a second function for choice a number random button 1 to 5 button, in my example is an for boucle loop, I want to see the choice button, (color change for 1 second or 2 second) same click button manually and I want see how is first button selected, second button selected when I place sleep function for slow choice and see button selected by computer, hope help you ? very many thanks ! (I'm new in development)

Comment: @DonMag Very good exactly what i wanted, i will look where is my mistake, really many thanks for the help ! I adapt this solution on my program, I don't think this way :) many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you **never** want to use `sleep(2)` - it freezes your program for 2 seconds, and nothing else can happen. There are ***rare*** exceptions, but you definitely do not want that here.

It's still a bit confusing what you really want to do. Your question says *"soundEnd boolean value when my mp3 ending play"*?

So, here is an example - using some of your code.

- on `viewDidLoad()`

  - draw a grid of 12 white buttons on a red background
- on `viewDidAppear()`

  - start a sound playing
  - set the border of the first button to black
- when the sound stops

  - set the button border back to white
  - start the second sound
  - set the border of the second button to black

This will loop through the number of sound clips you have:

```
class SoundTestViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    let squareSize  = 100
    let borderSpace = 20

    var myPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    // start at -1 so first call to "play next" will increment it to 0
    var soundNumber: Int = -1

    // replace with your mp3 file names
    let mp3FileNames: [String] = [
        "clip1",
        "clip2",
        "clip3",
        "clip4",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let zone3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width:   view.frame.width-20, height: view.frame.height-20))
        zone3.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(squareDraw(contentView: zone3))
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        playNextSoundFile()
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        player.stop()
        if let subview = self.view.viewWithTag(soundNumber + 1) as? UIButton {
            subview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        }
        playNextSoundFile()
    }

    func playNextSoundFile() {
        soundNumber += 1
        if soundNumber > mp3FileNames.count - 1 {
            soundNumber = 0
        }

        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: mp3FileNames[soundNumber], withExtension: ".mp3") else {
            // mp3 file not found in bundle
            return
        }

        do {
            if let subview = self.view.viewWithTag(soundNumber + 1) as? UIButton {
                subview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            }

            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

            self.myPlayer = sound

            // set the audio player delegate to self
            sound.delegate = self

            sound.numberOfLoops = 0
            sound.prepareToPlay()
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            print("error initializing audio player")
        }
    }


    func squareDraw(contentView : UIView) ->UIView {

        let widthScreen: Int = Int(contentView.bounds.width)
        let heightScreen: Int  = Int(contentView.bounds.height)

        let scaleFactorX = (widthScreen*100/((3 * squareSize) + (4 * borderSpace)))
        let scaleFactorY = (heightScreen*100/((4 * squareSize) + (5 * borderSpace)))

        let squareSizeScaleX = (squareSize * scaleFactorX)/100
        let squareSizeScaleY = (squareSize * scaleFactorY)/100

        let borderSpaceScaleX = (borderSpace * scaleFactorX)/100
        let borderSpaceScaleY = (borderSpace * scaleFactorY)/100

        let originY = 0
        var Tag = 0
        for yCoord in 1...4 {
            for xCoord in 1...3 {
                Tag = Tag + 1
                let k = button(CGRect(x: xCoord * (squareSizeScaleX + borderSpaceScaleX) - squareSizeScaleX, y: originY + (yCoord * (squareSizeScaleY + borderSpaceScaleY) - squareSizeScaleY), width: squareSizeScaleX, height: squareSizeScaleY), tag: Tag)
                contentView.addSubview(k)

            }
        }

        return contentView
    }

    func button(_ rect: CGRect, tag: Int) ->UIView {

        let myButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        myButton.frame = CGRect(x:CGFloat(rect.minX), y:CGFloat(rect.minY), width:CGFloat(rect.width), height:CGFloat(rect.height))
        myButton.tag = tag
        myButton.backgroundColor = .white
        myButton.layer.borderWidth = 5
        myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        return myButton
    }

}
```

If that is not really what you are trying to do, maybe it will at least get you in the right direction.

Comment: Very good exactly what i wanted, i will look where is my mistake, really many thanks for the help !